# What is wrong with this lambda function?

Tags: haskell

I am at the beggining of Get Programming with Haskell and just learned lambda functions. As an exercise I tried to convert the following example to use a lambda.

```
calcChange owed given =
  if   change > 0
  then change
  else 0
  where change = given - owed
```

`calcChange 9 7` returns `0` and `calcChange 7 9` returns `2`

Now, here is my attempt

```
calcChange owed given =
  (\change ->
      if   change > 0
      then change
      else 0
  ) given - owed
```

which fails: `calcChange 7 9` returns `2` but `calcChange 9 7` returns `-2`.

What is wrong with my attempt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example, `change` has value `given - owned`. In the second, simply `given`. The results of that lambda then have `owned` subtracted from them.

You likely meant to send `given - owned` as the argument to that lambda.

```
calcChange owed given =
  (\change ->
      if   change > 0
      then change
      else 0
  ) (given - owed)
```

Or, using `$`:

```
calcChange owed given =
  (\change ->
      if   change > 0
      then change
      else 0
  ) $ given - owed
```

Answer (score 2):

The lambda only receives `given`.

```
(\change ->
      if  change > 0
      then change
      else 0
) given - owed
```

==>

```
(if given > 0 then given else 0) - owed
```

==> (since `given` is positive)

```
given - owed
```

Answer (score 1):

Operators all have precedence levels between 0 and 9. Function application behaves like an operator with precedence 10, though, so

```
(\change ->
  if   change > 0
  then change
  else 0
) given - owed
```

behaves like

```
((\change ->
  if   change > 0
  then change
  else 0
) given) - owed
```

not

```
(\change ->
  if   change > 0
  then change
  else 0
) (given - owed)
```